# PHP Code in XML which is generated in PHP

Tags: php, xml, variables

I have a problem with XML data generated by a PHP file.

here is my code:

```
$requestXmlBody .= "<PictureURL>";

    //find black

  while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
  {
    $posblack = strpos($row->image, $findBLACK);
    if ($posblack !== false) 
    {
    echo $row->image;
    }
  }
    $requestXmlBody .= "</PictureURL>";
```

This code will generate the XML Code

```
<PictureURL></PictureURL>
```

but not the name I fetch from the database. The database query is working but my problem ist to have it inserted between the XML code. 
Usually a variable is inserted like this

```
$requestXmlBody .= '<PictureURL>$variable</PictureURL>';
```

I just don't know how to wrap this around my database query.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Double check that you are getting rows returned by assigning $rows outside of your while loop and echoing the count.

Comment: You are mixing string concatenation (for the xml tags) with a raw `echo` (for the image URL). Decide on one. Place both in the loop and if block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are echo'ing `$row->image` instead of appending to `$requestXmlBody`

Change your code to:

```
$requestXmlBody .= $row->image;
```

Comment: Are you ever going to have more than one result?  If so, you should have the <PictureURL> part added to the while loop.

Comment: It's only one result. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis)) {
  $posblack = strpos($row->image, $findBLACK);
  if ($posblack !== false) {
    $requestXmlBody .= "<PictureURL>";
    $requestXmlBody .= $row->image;
    $requestXmlBody .= "</PictureURL>";
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked with the '$requestXmlBody .= "<PictureURL>";' outside the loop. Thanks a lot. this made my day :)